# Rally SDK 1.32 - Efficiently determine "active" projects

Tags: rally

I'm working on some custom reporting which needs requires a list of active projects within Rally. Although projects in Rally have an active indicator that I could read, we determined this wasn't the best source of truth given that this field isn't maintained regularly or consistently within our organization.

We decided a Rally project/team is active if:

**They have at least 1 user story with a LastUpdateDate within the last 30 days**

I'm trying to figure out how to pull this information from Rally in the most efficient way possible.

The obvious solution of pulling every project (over 200) with their associated user stories seems too burdensome and inefficient.

Is there a way to grab every project name within a workspace along with the date of the most recently updated user story? Or even better, only retrieve projects that qualify as "active"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is probably to do a query for stories ordered by LastUpdateDate DESC, LastUpdateDate > 30 days ago, pageSize 1 for each project.  Then just filter out the ones where there were no results.

I was trying to come up with a clever solution using revision history but that object only stores the workspace.

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping for a more clever solution too. This solution works though. Thanks for your help!